# Class members in Dash app/Approaches on localhost

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I spent quite some time to build complex apps in Dash. I have interfaces for "custom components", wrappers for `id`-`property` pairs, a way to keep track of my component `id`s and means to re-use the components I created.

I'm using the several transforms provided by `dash-extensions`, without which some of my solutions would not work.

I mirrored custom types in my program logic code by providing converter classes, which convert custom type objects (e.g. `Measurement`) to and from dictionary representations, which I can then pass through dash callbacks.

Now, in a couple of situations, we are actually using Dash as a "desktop app", thus, it is not actually run on a server, but `localhost`, and there is only ever one user. Thus, the "no globals" restriction is void, isn't it? I could safely rely on global constants in my Dash app, *if* I only run it on `localhost`, correct?

Moreover, I create my custom components inside a class, which also has a method `registerCallbacks()` that creates all callbacks necessary for the component. These callbacks could then also rely on class members, correct? So I could save the converter functions and would not need to pass my "objects" via Inputs/Outputs.

Are there any problems with this idea?

Comment: Hard to answer some of these questions without looking at code, and there's probably too much here for a single question. I'd say to continue avoiding globals as much as you can. If you need to store something, use the [`dcc.Store`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) component.

Comment: For the standalone app running on localhost for one single user, if the app is dedicated to be used like so, then the code can take advantage of that and use global variables, which makes things a lot easier for initializing/updating components. Provided that these globals are accessible from your callbacks, so for the second part I'm not sure, if your components are loaded from a generic class (ie. used in other dash apps) that also register callbacks for them. Some code example would help to picture the thing.

Comment: I totally understand that it is hard to give detailed answers without any exemple code, thus I appreciate your comments even more. They are helpful already and I will update my question with a concise example as soon as I see fit. For now, I know that I can experiment in that direction